# PC does not wake up from hibernation/hybrid sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, wake-up, hybrid-sleep

Every time my Desktop PC goes into hibernation or hybrid sleep, I'm unable to resume it. To make a fresh boot I have to disconnect it from power source for about 10 seconds and then turn on.

### Solutions tried:

- Troubleshooting - no issues found;
- Disabling hibernation completely through `powercfg` command;
- Updating BIOS to the latest version;
- Updating video adapter driver, also tried rolling back to previous driver;
- Both keyboard and mouse power management have "allow this device to wake the computer" checked.
- Tried toggling "Suspend to RAM" in BIOS ACPI settings.

None of the above worked.

### PC information:

- **OS Name:** Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- **Version:** 10.0.15063 Build 15063
- **System Type:** x64-based PC
- **Processor:** AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor, 3500 Mhz
- **BIOS:** American Megatrends Inc. P1.80, 10/31/2012
- **SMBIOS Version:**  2.6
- **BaseBoard Manufacturer:** ASRock

Comment: Is it working in safe mode?

Comment: Whether you are using Laptop? So did u try with Battery mode and Adapter mode. In both u have same problem?
Cant You Upgrade your windows 10 to latest build.

Comment: Does the event log suggest anything?

Comment: @Dave where exactly should I look or what should I look for in Even Viewer? there are so many entries.